# Using jQuery CSS Property to Center an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Here is a piece of normal code from my site for centered images:

```
<img width="600" alt="Image" src="img-src.jpg" style="width: 600px;"
 class="center" />
```

I am using inline styles with a class of center (the css for center is `margin:0 auto;`) to center my images on a page. I cannot set a standard width for images with the center class because the images vary in widths.

I know jQuery has a CSS property and that got me to thinking if I can use jQuery to read the image width from the image properties and automatically insert `width: *image-size pulled from img properties*px;`to any image that has a class of center thus eliminating the need for me to manually set the image width for every image.

Please provide examples as I not fluent in JS enough to write this myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about giving your images a container with `text-align : center`:

```
<div style="text-align : center;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YfFht/

A CSS solution will be good for performance.

Comment: I attempted that and the image was huge! The image was 350px and it rendered at 950px. Ideas? Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind - There was some conflicting code I missed. It works. Thank You. Now Question - Why does this work for images (`text-align: center` when it is in the above format when if you put it inside the `<img>` tag it does not?

Comment: @Lynda You can set a `max-width` CSS property for your images so they only grow to a specific size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align. See the **Summary** in this link: `text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.`. That's just how `text-align` works.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="center">
  <img alt="Image" src="img-src.jpg" style="width: 600px;" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute; /*or fixed*/
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use load to detect when image is downloaded. In anonymous function for each one get the width and apply it as a css property.

```
$('img').load( function() {
   $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
});
```

Comment: Make sure you bind to the images before any of them have loaded. Or alternatively run the code when `window.load` fires so you know all the images are available to get their dimensions.

Comment: As Jasper mentions, you could use window.load and then bind with `$('img').each( function...` instead. If you placed my code in a `window.load` the code would never fire because the resources have already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Remove inline styles from the `img` elements and then try this code on window load event which will ensure that all the resources on the page are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    //You can grab the img dimensions as below.
    var width = $('imgSelector').width();
    var height = $('imgSelector').height();

    //Use `css` method to set the styles on the element.
    $('imgSelector').css({
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    //E.g - this will set the width and height of all the images on the page
    $('img').each(function(){
        $(this).css({
             width: width,
             height: height
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image in a parent container such as a div which has the width and height set to the maximum you would allow. Then use the following jQuery plugin to center them inside the div:

http://boxlight.github.com/bl-jquery-image-center/

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking you only need to do this:

```
$("img.center").load(function(){
   var currentImage = $(this);
   currentImage.css("width",currentImage.width()+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery snippet sets the parent's `text-align` CSS property to `center` for all `.center` images, which I think will accomplish the same without setting widths:

```
$('img.center').parent().css('text-align','center');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/qd3ab/)

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking at `$("img").width()` this will give you the width in pixels using the integer format (so if the width is "`width: 100px;`", this would be "100"). But in order for this to work, every image has to have `width=""` attribute set, otherwise you'll have an error and no value returned.

Two links to check out would be:

http://api.jquery.com/width/

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/